# Performance when execute a process from other process

Tags: linux, bash, performance, command-line-interface

I have an application that performs a conversion process from input data, his size is about 100-150 kb, and returns a JSON.

This application (written in C) is used by another app (written in nodejs). My question is, assuming a high degree of usage, even concurrent, which option gives better performance?:

- passing the input and output through the file system (an input file and generates an output file)
- passing the input and output through stdin and stdout respectively

Currently I have developed it based on the second option, but I have the doubt presented regarding the performance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One typical tipping point is when your data is no longer small enough to fit into memory - before then files are worse; after that point files are better. Take concurrency into account, too; 1024 processes taking 4 meg each will exhaust 4G just as well as a single big process (though in the former case the OS scheduler will probably defer execution of the ones it can't give resources to).

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to be sure which will be faster.  It *may* depend on the file system type, the performance characteristics of the storage device, how the applications write and read the data ... and other things.

Either way, my intuition is that the performance difference between the two approaches will not be significant.

My advice would be:

1. Continue with your current approach.
2. When you have it working **measure** the performance.
3. If the performance is **acceptable**, stop: you have a working solution.
4. If the performance is **not acceptable**, implement the other approach and see if it is faster.

---

(I don't think it is likely to be much effort to implement both approaches and test them, but effort is effort, and it is not worth expending effort to optimize something that doesn't *need* to be optimized.)